# using PubNub for multi users chatting

Tags: chat, channel, multi-user, pubnub

I'm designing an application that using PubNub for real-time message.
I'm facing with an issue about 1-to-1 chatting.
This is my scenario :

I have an user A, so if A wants to receive all messages from another, A must subscribe a public channel, called PUB channel.

User B know the public channel of A, so B or another can send messsage to this channel.
Right now that fine.

BUT when i open the app, i want to display the list of users that i've messaged or offline messages that a NEW person sent me.

I can get all messages from my public channel. but how to filter with the user? in case of a lot of messages, this is so difficult.

With all of them , i only want get messages of me and C, or me and B...etc
Anyone have ideas for this?
Thanks,

Answer (score 1):

## PubNub Multi-user Chat and Communication

Each user has their own dedicated channel.  Bob has the `"bob12345"` channel and Sally has `"sally12345"` channel.  When users want to speak to each other, they send message directly to the owner's channel name.  Bob will `pubnub.publish({...})` on Sally's channel.

```
pubnub.publish({ 
    channel : 'sally12345', 
    message : { from: 'bob12345', message: 'Hi!' }
});
```

> Note that you will want to grant global write access using [PubNub Access Manager to Grant Write-only access globally](https://www.pubnub.com/docs/javascript/tutorial/access-manager.html).  Also grant read-only access to the owner of the channel.

Each user should always have their messages stored locally on their device or load all history and save.

### How to Load a Conversation between two users only

If you want to load the messages from a specific user's conversation, you will need to publish to a side channel to index the messages for future retrieval.  You can do this by publishing to a private side channel that is a concatenation of Bob's and Sally's channel name.

```
// Publish a second time to index the message in a side channel.
pubnub.publish({ 
    channel : 'history-sally12345-bob12345', 
    message : { from: 'bob12345', message: 'Hi!' }
});
```

Now you can load history for this specific user.

```
// Load history for dedicated conversation.
pubnub.history({ 
    channel  : 'history-sally12345-bob12345', 
    callback : function(messages) { 
        console.log(messages);
    }
});
```

Comment: I'm thinking your way,with Public channel to receive all request and history channel to get conversation between 2 users.

Comment: In case of a new user message me, or when i'm offline, i mean user A, A message me 3 times, 1-2-3, i will replace message 1 with 2, and 2 with 3, so 3rd message will store on Public channel(also store all messages in my history channel with A). But i'm concern about when on public channel have a lot of messages, like 2000 users message, if i want replace 1st message of A, i must get all messages, so i dont know i can do this or not?

Comment: You will want to load all messages in this case or just place a limit on the number of messages and ignore any modifications.  Also I have a hidden URL that may have what you are looking for when it comes to data sync changes.  Send me an email to stephen@pubnub.com and I can send you the link.