# Possibility to inform channel member using Pubnub

Tags: c#, .net, pubnub

I am trying to build a chat application using Pubnub.

I want to notify the people who are added to a newly created channel to join to that chat..

How can I achieve this using pubnub. I've gone through the document but didn't find anything related to it.

Is there any possibility to do this? If so, can you please let me know the way to accomplish this task?

Thank you.

Comment: a brief hint, you can use a "lobby" room that each user subscribes.  you can send a message to the lobby room `{"event":"new-room","channel":"my-new-room-id"}`. and users can choose to join or not.

Comment: there are other approaches as well.  have each user subscribe to a `user-id` channel.  send 'invites' to each user's channel when a new room is created.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Pubnub for chat in ios](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36643467/pubnub-for-chat-in-ios)

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36643467/pubnub-for-chat-in-ios/36685644#36685644 - this should answer your question. But contact PubNub Support if you still have more questions.